# How to make custom button design in Android

Tags: android

The button I'm looking to make has text (Apply), an image (tick mark) and an outer border coloured white background, and an inner background with grey color as you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Comment: I already answered this question a couple of days ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787766/how-can-i-develop-this-kind-of-button/37789806#37789806

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`FloatingActionButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html).

This extends ImageButton so you will need to create an image of what you want your button to look like. You can make have circular boundaries using XML styles.

A related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884202/custom-circle-button) has more options and detail.